# How to parse query strings in Dart?

Tags: query-string, dart

How do I parse query strings safely in [Dart](http://dartlang.org)?

Let's assume I have `q` string with the value of:

```
?page=main&action=front&sid=h985jg9034gj498g859gh495
```

Ideally the code should work both in the server and client, but for now I'll settle for a working client-side code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made a simple package for that purpose exactly: https://github.com/kaisellgren/QueryString

Example:

```dart
import 'package:query_string/query_string.dart');

void main() {
  var q = '?page=main&action=front&sid=h985jg9034gj498g859gh495&enc=+Hello%20&empty';

  var r = QueryString.parse(q);

  print(r['page']); // "main"
  print(r['asdasd']); // null
}
```

The result is a [`Map`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/Map.html). Accessing parameters is just a simple `r['action']` and accessing a non-existant query parameter is `null`.

Now, to install, add to your `pubspec.yaml` as a dependency:

```yaml
dependencies:
  query_string: any
```

And run `pub install`.

The library also handles decoding of things like `%20` and `+`, and works even for empty parameters.

It does not support "array style parameters", because they are not part of the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specification.

Comment: 10 yo solution, unfortunately the dependency is deprecated.

Answer (score 18):

The simpler, the better. Look for the [splitQueryString](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Uri#id_splitQueryString) static method of class Uri.

```
Map<String, String> splitQueryString(String query, {Encoding encoding: UTF8}) 

Returns the query split into a map according to the rules specified for 
FORM post in the HTML 4.01 specification section 17.13.4. Each key and value 
in the returned map has been decoded. If the query is the empty string an 
empty map is returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

all of the answers are pretty much outdated.

Quickest and easiest way:

```
Uri uri = Uri(query: data);

var queryParameters = uri.queryParameters;

var myValue = queryParameters["my_value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I done that just like this:

```
 Map<String, String> splitQueryString(String query) {
    return query.split("&").fold({}, (map, element) {
      int index = element.indexOf("=");
      if (index == -1) {
        if (element != "") {
          map[element] = "";
        }
      } else if (index != 0) {
        var key = element.substring(0, index);
        var value = element.substring(index + 1);
        map[key] = value;
      }
      return map;
    });
 }
```

I took it from  [splitQueryString](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Uri#id_splitQueryString)